# Do we need to create the target output file in Informatica before starting the workflow?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am performing some mappings and want to store them in a new flat file (.CSV). But this requires the creation of a target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not require to create a target file before running the workflow, informatica creates the file for you by the file_name given by you in session.